# Markup vs mark-up vs. mark up for prices

Tags: word-choice

I am very confused by the use of the above three terms. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_(business)) "A markup is the difference between the selling price of a good or service and cost". However I very often see the use of mark-up and mark up and I could not really find anything on this issue because there are many questions on mark up languages and other related topics.

To be honest I am not sure if this is the right stack exchange for this kind of question and apologize in advance if it is not.

Comment: I think it is off-topic as the word-choice tag is about "choosing the right words for the context of your writing" not the word in general, but I'm not sure. This may fit better on English StackExchange,

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary lists all three forms.

Comment: @rolfedh Funny i first wanted to post my question there but changed my mind based on their guidelines

Comment: @Max M I just realized I'm not familiar with their guidelines. Are they saying you shouldn't post questions like this one?

Comment: A price **markup** (noun) is very different from somebody who **marks up** a price (verb). And the computer language is something else. Context determines the spelling.

Comment: Max, FYI: EL&U stack exchange is the right place to ask a question on word usage or spelling *after you've done your research and couldn't resolve the issue*. Since any good dictionary would resolve the differences between the different word usages/spellings, your question would quickly be closed on that site, either as off-topic ("lack of research") or (as you've found) as a duplicate regarding hyphenation. Your question certainly doesn't meet our own Writing.SE requirements. The dictionary is an essential tool for all writers. [Try this really useful one](https://www.onelook.com). :-)